# Why the content of file pointer is null before using fscanf() and after using fscanf() it becomes the rest of the strings present in the file?

Tags: c

Why the content of the `ptr_01` is printed as NULL when I used (1). But the same is printed as the remaining string (content of the file after 1 `fscanf()`). Why?

I still don't get how does fscanf works?

When I used (3) 2nd string of the file prints and the pointer shifts again by 1 string. I mean, (4) then prints the rest of the content. But if `ptr_01` has the content of the file as it is printed using (2) & (4) why it is printing NULL with (1) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_01;
    char string_01[200];
    ptr_01 = fopen("myread.txt", "r");
    printf("%s ", *ptr_01); // Why this prints as NULL?? --------(1)
    fscanf(ptr_01, "%s", string_01);
    printf("%s", *ptr_01); // While this prints as the rest of the content of the file. ---------(2)
    fscanf(ptr_01, "%s", string_01); -----(3)
    printf("%s", *ptr_01); ---(4)
    fclose(ptr_01);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A file pointer doesn't point to some text. It's an abstract handle you can only use within file functions such as `fprintf`, `fscanf`, `fclose` etc. `printf("%s ", *ptr_01)` makes no sense whatsoever; the output you see is the result of _undefined behaviour_ (google that term).

Answer (score 2):

The return value of *fopen* is not a string containing the content of the file. You need to use one of the file-reading functions for that, like *getc* or *fgets*.

Example:

```
ptr_01 = fopen("myread.txt", "r");
if (ptr_01 != NULL) {
  fgets(string_01, sizeof string_01, ptr_01);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `FILE *` like `ptr_01` points to an object that stores information *about* a stream (text or binary, input or output or append, wide or narrow character, current position, any error state) - it does not point to a specific position within the file.

You are not meant to dereference or manipulate `ptr_01` directly - you just pass it as an argument to the various `stdio` routines to read from or write to the stream, or to test for end of file and other conditions.